# Is B1 visa suitable for attending PyCon US?

Tags: visas, usa, b1-b2-visas

Is B1 visa suitable for attending software conferences like PyCon US? In PyCon you can typically engage in three types of activities:

1. Get some training in tutorials
2. Attend keynotes/conferences
3. Participate in free software sprints.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, the [B-1 visa category is appropriate for participation](https://travel.state.gov/content/visas/en/visit/visitor.html) in the PyCon conference.

> Visitor visas are nonimmigrant visas for persons who want to enter the United States temporarily for business (visa category B-1), tourism, pleasure or visiting (visa category B-2), or a combination of both purposes (B-1/B-2).

One example of permitted activities for a B-1 visa is to ***attend a scientific, educational, professional, or business convention or conference.***

While you might not require one, you may want to include an invitation letter from the PyCon organizers:

> [Invitation letters](https://us.pycon.org/2017/venue/travel/): Visitor visa applicants may need letters or other documents indicating the purpose of their visit, evidence of funds to cover accommodation and food, and so on. The PyCon organizers are happy to provide an invitation letter if you need one; we do suggest, however, that you check with your local embassy or consulate, as requirements differ from country to country. Please email pycon-reg@python.org to request an invitation letter from the conference.